# Seasonal differencing applied to exogenous variable (xreg)? Forecast package R by Hyndman

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting, arima, seasonality

Im currently working on specifying a seasonal ARIMA model with an exogenous variable. I'm using the forecast package developed by Hyndman for this. I have specified the following:

```
Arima(endogenous, order = c(1,1,0), seasonal = c(0,1,0), xreg = exogenous)
```

**Q:** I was wondering if the seasonal differencing is also applied to the exogenous variable?

In relation to the order Hyndman does mention: "The order argument specifies the order of the ARIMA error model. If differencing is specified, then the differencing is applied to all variables in the regression model before the model is estimated" https://otexts.com/fpp2/regarima.html

However, it is unclear to me if the seasonal differencing, and any other seasonal parameters that are set are also applied to the exogenous variable.

Thank you!